# can we call WaitForSingleObject multiple times from single thread for Mutex

Tags: c++, winapi, mutex

We have wrapper of mutex object.Constructor of this wrapper creates a mutex . Also it has Enter and Leave functions which basically calls WaitForSingleObject and ReleaseMutex .

Now program thread is executing multiple funcions like

```
void A()
{
  mutexObj->Enter();
  B();
  mutexObj->Leave();
}

void B()
{
  mutexObj->Enter();
  C();
  mutexObj->Leave();
}
```

I am seeing thread being stopped at B() function. What I have read about mutex is that we can call WaitforSingleObjects multiple times from same thread, then why my code is getting blocked.

Here is implementation of mutex

```
CMutex::CMutex(const TCHAR *name)
   :  m_hMutex(CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, name))   
{
}

    CMutex::~CMutex()
    {
       if (m_hMutex != NULL)
       {
          CloseHandle(m_hMutex);
          m_hMutex= NULL;
       }
    }

     bool Enter(DWORD milli= INFINITE){
         HANDLE handles[1]= { m_hMutex };
         return(MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1,handles,FALSE, milli,QS_ALLINPUT) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
        }
     void Leave(){ReleaseMutex(m_hMutex);}
```

Comment: Can you show the constructor of your mutex?

Comment: added implementation of mutex

Comment: `Enter` also returns, if it doesn't take ownership of the mutex. In other words, your code - as posted - is **not** threadsafe. Why are you using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`?

Comment: We have no idea what your code does because we don't know what `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` is. You gave it the same name as a well-known Win32 function, but your version is different. What with it having a mere three parameters. There are many good implementations of mutex classes in existence. Why are you making another?

Comment: You still have the wrong arguments for `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`. Why not post your real code?

Comment: MsgWaitForMultipleObjects is just a wrapper over windows MsgWaitForMultipleObjects call

Comment: @Jonathan Which argument is wrong?

Comment: @IInspectable: The OP has updated the code again and the arguments are right now. But the code is still confused about `Enter`/`Leave` vs `enter`/`leave`, which indicates this is not the real code.

Comment: Yes , its  not the real code but this is just to give idea what code is doing

Comment: My comment still holds: `Enter` can return without taking ownership of the mutex. Your described behavior is what one would expect. Also, your code is not exception safe: It will not release a mutex in case of an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a mutex can be waited on multiple times within the same thread.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says as much:

> After a thread obtains ownership of a mutex, it can specify the same mutex in repeated calls to the wait-functions without blocking its execution. This prevents a thread from deadlocking itself while waiting for a mutex that it already owns. To release its ownership under such circumstances, the thread must call ReleaseMutex once for each time that the mutex satisfied the conditions of a wait function.

That being said, your code is not safe because you are ignoring the result of the wait, so you are not making sure you actually own the mutex lock before accessing something that is protected by the mutex.

Try this instead:

```
class CMutex
{
public:
    CMutex(const TCHAR *name = NULL);
    ~CMutex();
    bool Enter(DWORD milli = INFINITE);
    void Leave();
};

CMutex::CMutex(const TCHAR *name)
   :  m_hMutex(CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, name))   
{
}

CMutex::~CMutex()
{
    if (m_hMutex != NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(m_hMutex);
        m_hMutex = NULL;
    }
}

bool CMutex::Enter(DWORD milli)
{
    return (WaitForSingleObject(m_hMutex, milli) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
}

void CMutex::Leave()
{
    ReleaseMutex(m_hMutex);
}
```

```
void A()
{
    if (mutexObj->Enter()) // <-- CHECK THE RESULT!!!
    {
        B();
        mutexObj->Leave();
    }
}

void B()
{
    if (mutexObj->Enter()) // <-- CHECK THE RESULT!!!
    {
        C();
        mutexObj->Leave();
    }
}
```

I would take it a step further by using RAII to manage the lock:

```
class CMutex
{
public:
    CMutex(const TCHAR *name = NULL);
    ~CMutex();
    bool Enter(DWORD milli = INFINITE);
    void Leave();

    class Lock
    {
    private:
        CMutex &m_mutex;
        bool m_locked;
    public:
        Lock(CMutex &mutex);
        ~Lock();
        bool isLocked() const;
    };
};

CMutex::CMutex(const TCHAR *name)
   :  m_hMutex(CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, name))   
{
}

CMutex::~CMutex()
{
    if (m_hMutex != NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(m_hMutex);
        m_hMutex = NULL;
    }
}

bool Enter(DWORD milli)
{
    return (WaitForSingleObject(m_hMutex, milli) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
}

void Leave()
{
    ReleaseMutex(m_hMutex);
}

CMutex::Lock::Lock(CMutex &mutex)
    : m_mutex(mutex), m_locked(mutex.Enter())
{
}

CMutex::Lock::~Lock()
{
    if (m_locked)
    {
        m_mutex.Leave();
        m_locked = false;
    }
}

CMutex::Lock::isLocked() const
{
    return m_locked;
}
```

```
void A()
{
    CMutex::Lock lock(*mutexObj);
    if (lock.isLocked()) // <-- CHECK THE RESULT!!!
        B();
}

void B()
{
    CMutex::Lock lock(*mutexObj);
    if (lock.isLocked()) // <-- CHECK THE RESULT!!!
        C();
}
```

Or even:

```
class CMutex
{
public:
    CMutex(const TCHAR *name = NULL);
    ~CMutex();
    bool Enter(DWORD milli = INFINITE);
    void Leave();

    class Lock
    {
    private:
        CMutex &m_mutex;
    public:
        Lock(CMutex &mutex);
        ~Lock();
    };
};

CMutex::CMutex(const TCHAR *name)
   :  m_hMutex(CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, name))   
{
    if (!m_hMutex)
        throw std::runtime_error("cannot create the mutex handle");
}

CMutex::~CMutex()
{
    CloseHandle(m_hMutex);
    m_hMutex = NULL;
}

bool Enter(DWORD milli)
{
    return (WaitForSingleObject(m_hMutex, milli) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
}

void Leave()
{
    ReleaseMutex(m_hMutex);
}

CMutex::Lock::Lock(CMutex &mutex)
    : m_mutex(mutex)
{
    if (!m_mutex.Enter())
        throw std::runtime_error("cannot lock the mutex");
}

CMutex::Lock::~Lock()
{
    m_mutex.Leave();
}
```

```
void A()
{
    CMutex::Lock lock(*mutexObj);
    B();
}

void B()
{
    CMutex::Lock lock(*mutexObj);
    C();
}
```